# Washer doesn’t spin

Tags: washer

I have a top load direct drive whirlpool washer. It does not spin at all in the spin cycle but  the motor,pump,motor coupler spins. I checked the drive block and no wear or tear. I replaced the clutch but still no spin. But one thing I notice there is black oil leaking and dripping onto the clutch cause the oldclutch was very dirty and black  And when I removed the spin tube there’s oil leaking by the seal I believe. Ps the lid switch is good. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the model# it sounds like you are looking at the correct things. Even a greasy clutch would try to turn if the water had been removed.

Comment: Just found out it is the transmission